# Chrome Workspaces: Changes in Elements>Styles not saved to Sources Tab

Tags: css, angular, linux, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to setup Google Chrome Developer Tools Workspaces, so that I can edit my CSS in the Chrome Element Inspector and save the changes to my source files on my hard drive.

I've got Workspaces working so far that I can make edits in the Sources tab and save the edits to the local file. But that's not what I want! I want to save the edits I'm making to my CSS files in the Chrome Element Inspector.

Please help!

(Another very old thread suggested using Google Canary, but I think it's outdated, and also it's no option for me, because it's not supported on Linux)

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/workspaces/

"Step 2: Save a CSS change to disk" from that link is not working for me.

I'm using Angular. I think now it is not working because of Angular.

[image: Changed Code in the Element Inspector]
[image: Sources Tab not updating]

Answer (score 0):

It seems you were trying to edit the css file under 'src' folder. If I'm correct, you are working on Reactjs or Vue.js type of environment. Unfortunately, google articulated that this is not working for now.

'Limitations'
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/workspaces

But, still you can manipulate the css file under 'public' folder (in reactjs case). And this is an walkaround I take.